# How do you convert a double to a formatted string?

Tags: c#, string, double

I searched a lot about this problem but the only results I get is with numbers like 5.04
My number is >1 so for example 0.8
number.ToString("F2") is the way I tried but haven't found a format yet that worked.
So Do anybody know how to show a double number in a label?

Comment: Also includes a reference to "label" so probably a label on a WinForms label - though looking at Label's attributes this fact shouldn't affect the answer.

Comment: Try being more detailed about what you consider "right" or "working". Give example of what you tried, what did you get get and what did you want to get.

Also as already pointed out, you probably mean "your number < 1".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
string s = String.Format("{0:0.00}", 0.8);
```

Comment: dont work.It return everytime 0.my number is declared with       double t = 90 / 180; and my string is                       label5.Text = String.Format("{0:0.00}", t);

Comment: that's because you're dividing two ints.  If you had used `double t = 90.0/180;` or `double t = (double)90/180;` it would have worked.  You have a general coding error.

Comment: Thanks it works now!Sorry for that error I'm really new in c#

Answer (score 2):

The [article on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kfsatb94.aspx) may be of help regarding formatting a Decimal number in a variety of formats. Scroll a bit down and view the examples given and their output they would provide.

Comment: I seen the page before but as I said their is no example/format for 0.xxx

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you are asking, but what's wrong with:

```
string formatted = string.Format("{0:F2}",0.8);
```

It produces 0.80, which I thought is what you were looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Formatted two decimal places:

```
String.Format("{0:0.00}", 123.4567);      // "123.46"

String.Format("{0:0.00}", 123.4);         // "123.40"

String.Format("{0:0.00}", 123.0);         // "123.00"
```